# How to trace a program execution with ptrace?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I've been trying to use the system call "ptrace" (using the PTRACE_SINGLESTEP macro) to trace the execution of a simple application.

While recording the execution of the program I would like to skip the useless part of the reading to only follow from the 'main' of my application. Because whenever I launch my tracer I get around 100k execution steps.

Cordialy

Comment: Could you share your original program, which prints every executed address? I have no ptrace experience and I would be interested to examine such a simple example of its usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to insert a breakpoint at `main` entry, wait for a `SIGTRAP` to arrive, restore the instruction under the breakpoint, and single-step from there.